# ¿Cómo Cambiar la ruta de descarga usando selenium en una iteración en la misma pagina?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hola comunidad buenas tardes.
Busco su ayuda con una inquietud. Estoy automatizando con Python y selenium, un proceso de descarga de archivos. El proceso consiste en entrar a una pagina y logear el usuario y la contraseña de muchos usuarios y descargar un archivo.
Quisiera en la misma iteración ir cambiando la ruta de descarga del archivo, sin tener que hacer un nuevo llamado a la función del chrome driver, y tampoco a obtener nuevamente la pagina, ya que esto tarda mucho tiempo y es mas optimo cerrar sesión y logear el siguiente usuario.

Actualmente, tengo los siguientes códigos:

```
def iniciar_chrome():
    """Inicia Chrome con los parametros indicados y devuelve el Driver"""
    #Intalamos la version de ChromeDriver correspondiente
    ruta = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    #OPCIONES DE CHROME:
    options = Options() #instanciamos las opciones de chrome
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}") # define un user agent perzonalizado
    #options.add_argument("--windows-size=1000,1000") # para configurar un alto y ancho de la ventana
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized") #para maximar la ventana de Chrome (solo funciona si no se indica windows size)
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security") #desahabilita la politica del mismo origen o Same Origine Policy
    options.add_argument("--disable-    ") # para que no cargue las extensiones de Chrome
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications") # para bloquear notificaciones de Chrome 
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors") # Para ignorar el aviso "Su conexion no es segura"
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # deshabilita el modo sanbox, No se sabe para que sirve pero en tutoriales lo utilizan
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3") #para que Chromedriver no muestre nada en la terminal 
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content") # desactiva el aviso de "contenido no seguro"
    options.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check") # Evita el aviso de Chrome no es navegador por defecto
    options.add_argument("--no-first-run") # evita le ejecucion de ciertas tareas que se realizan la primera vez que se ejecuta Chrome
    options.add_argument("--no-proxy-server") # para no usar el proxy, sino conexiones directas
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") # evita que selenium sea detectados por sistemas anti bots
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/Probook/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1")
    #options.add_argument(CHROME_PROFILE_PATH)
    #options.add_argument("--incognito")


    #PARAMETROS A OMIITR EN EL INICIO DE CHROMEDRIVE
    exp_opt = [
        'enable-automation', #para que no muestre la notificacion de "Un software automatizado de pruebas está controlado Chrome"
        'ignore-certificate-errors', # para ignorar errores de cerficados (a veces estan caducados)
        'enable-logging' # para que no se muestre en la terminal "DevTools listening on..."
        ]
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", exp_opt)

    #PARAMETROS QUE DEFINEN LAS PREFERENCIAS EN CHROMEDRIVER
    prefs = {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2, # notificaciones: 0=preguntar | 1:permitir | 2:no permitir
        "intl.accept_languages"                                : ["es-ES","es"], # para definir el idioma del navegador
        "credentials_enable_service"                           : False, # para evitar que Chrome pregunte si queremos guardar la contresaña al loguearnos
        }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    #instancia el servicio de chromedriver
    s = Service(ruta) 
    #instanciamos webdriver de selenium con Chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options) #se añade el argmento OPTIONS
    #devolvemos el driver
    return driver
```

Y la función que hace la descarga de archivos, es la siguiente:

```
def descarga_archivos():
    year_consulta = 2022
    ruta = r"G:\Mi unidad\prueba\Claves.xlsx"
    book =  openpyxl.load_workbook(ruta, data_only=True)
    hoja = book["descarga_exogena"]
    rango = hoja['A2':'F'+str(hoja.max_column - 1)]
    driver = iniciar_chrome()
    driver.get('https://muisca.dian.gov.co/WebIdentidadLogin/?ideRequest=eyJjbGllbnRJZCI6IldvMGFLQWxCN3ZSUF8xNmZyUEkxeDlacGhCRWEiLCJyZWRpcmVjdF91cmkiOiJodHRwOi8vbXVpc2NhLmRpYW4uZ292LmNvL0lkZW50aWRhZFJlc3RfTG9naW5GaWx0cm8vYXBpL3N0cy92MS9hdXRoL2NhbGxiYWNrP3JlZGlyZWN0X3VyaT1odHRwJTNBJTJGJTJGbXVpc2NhLmRpYW4uZ292LmNvJTJGV2ViQXJxdWl0ZWN0dXJhJTJGRGVmTG9naW4uZmFjZXMiLCJyZXNwb25zZVR5cGUiOiIiLCJzY29wZSI6IiIsInN0YXRlIjoiIiwibm9uY2UiOiIiLCJwYXJhbXMiOnsidGlwb1VzdWFyaW8iOiJtdWlzY2EifX0%3D')
    time.sleep(10)
    for fila in rango:
        mail        = fila[0].value
        phone       = fila[1].value
        name        = fila[2].value
        folder_name = fila[3].value
        id          = fila[4].value
        password    = fila[5].value
        #SELECCIONAR EL TIPO DE DOCUMENTO ID
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'mat-select-value').click()
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-option-3").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element(By.NAME,"numDocumento").send_keys(id) 
        driver.find_element(By.NAME,"password").send_keys(password) 
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-checkbox-1").click()
        descarga = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "vistaDashboard:frmDashboard:anioSel")) 
        descarga.select_by_visible_text(f"{year_consulta}")
        ## ¿COMO CAMBIAR LA RUTA DE DESCARGAR?
```

La pregunta es: **¿Cómo puedo cambiar la ruta de descarga en la iteración de la función descarga_archivos?**
Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Una vez iniciado el Driver no parece que Selenium de una forma de cambiar la ruta de descarga dinamicamente, sin embargo, creo que puedas hacerlo obteniendo el link del archivo y descargarlo con requests y ahi si lo guardas donde quieras